# DXL regex range

Tags: regex, ibm-doors

I'm using dxl for DOORS. I want to catch an interval with open/close brackets like `[2.0;30[`

However I want to add the possibility to catch any special characters like `°C`, `^`, `%`, `.`, etc...

Is there something similar to non-whitespace character `"\S"` in dxl ?

My current regex without spec char:

```
regexp2("^(\\]|\\[)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+;[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\\]|\\[)$");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether that fits into your context, but something similar to \S would probably be `[^\t ]`

Comment: Thanks for the information! It would be great if you marked the question as answered, so that other users know about this as well.